# duplicates when using directorysearcher

Tags: powershell, active-directory, directorysearcher

I have a script that is using `DirectorySearcher` to query Active Directory for around ~13k users total every day.

I have been told that there are duplicates in my report, but I cannot figure out why.

The duplicates usually appear at the end of the report, and has been 6-7 users so far. The only difference between these users & their previous entry in the report is that their last logon time has changed (the time of which is seconds AFTER the script was initially started)

```
   #Get date for 3months back in datetime format
   $Date = (Get-Date).AddDays(-90)
   # Correct for daylight savings.
   If ($Date.IsDaylightSavingTime)
   {$Date = $Date.AddHours(-1)}
   # Convert the datetime value, in UTC, into the number of ticks since
   # 12:00 AM January 1, 1601.
   $Value = ($Date.ToUniversalTime()).Ticks - ([DateTime]"January 1, 1601").Ticks

   $Searcher = New-Object DirectoryServices.DirectorySearcher
   $Searcher.PageSize = 30000
   $Searcher.Filter = "(&(&(objectCategory=person)(objectClass=user))(lastLogonTimeStamp>=$value)(pwdLastSet>=$value)(!(userAccountControl:1.2.840.113556.1.4.803:=2)))"
   $Searcher.SearchRoot = 'LDAP://dc=contoso,dc=net'
   $results = $Searcher.FindAll() 

   foreach ($result in $results)
   {      
    # Fetches different attributes for each user
    # which is then appended to a .csv file via Add-Content
}
```

It feels like I am identifying additional users based on the fact that their last logon time was changed.. does anyone know anything about this? Maybe

How I can disable this behavior?

The script runs at 06:00:00.

Here is the last logon time for the duplicate entries

```
10/31/2015 06:00:24
10/31/2015 06:00:32 
10/31/2015 06:02:07 
10/31/2015 06:05:01 
10/31/2015 06:06:05 
10/31/2015 06:08:19 
10/31/2015 06:08:36
```

Comment: Why not use the `get-aduser` cmdlet?

Comment: I do not have it installed, and we are not allowed to install it

Comment: Add in a stopwatch counter and measure how long it takes for the command to complete.  I have a feeling the searcher does a final check to see what's changed since the query was first executed.

Comment: Thats what I think too, it takes around 12min for it to finish.. but I am hoping this check is documented somewhere, and that there is some way to disable it

Comment: I've read the msdn on the `findall()` method, the searcher object, the constructor, and the enumerator.  Nothing talks about the actual machinations of how the query works.  Though microsoft isn't in the habit of being that detailed.  I did see one thing interesting, add in a `dispose()` method when your done with the searcher.  Apparently garbage collector doesn't address it.

Comment: If you don't `fetch different attributes for each user` and just append them, do you still have duplicates?

Comment: Why not use the `PropertiesToLoad` property of the searcher, and then you don't have to query each user individually afterwards. Try `$Results = $Searcher.FindAll()|Group samAccountName|%{$_.Group|Select -last 1}` which will take a lot longer, but it will eliminate duplicates.